# CSS of loaded pages change when Infinite Scroll pages are loaded in

Tags: javascript, css, jquery-callback, infinite-scroll

I have Infinite Scroll, Isotope, and an audio player by the name of .mb_miniplayer_play on this site I am building. The problem I am having is when a new page is loaded in, the css on previously loaded pages change. Lets say page 2 is loaded in, the css of page 1 changes. but it is only of one element.

I have tried various things, but nothing seems to make all of the pages look and work properly.

The code is as follows:

```
  **//Audio jquery**

  $(function AudioEvents(){

    $(".audio").mb_miniPlayer({
    width:210,
    height:34,
    inLine:false,
    onEnd:playNext
    });

    var $audios = $('.audio');

    function playNext(idx) {
    var actualPlayer=$audios.eq(idx),
    $filteredAtoms = $container.data('isotope').$filteredAtoms,
    isotopeItemParent = actualPlayer.parents('.isotope-item'),
    isoIndex = $filteredAtoms.index( isotopeItemParent[0] ),
    nextIndex = ( isoIndex + 1 ) % $filteredAtoms.length;

    $filteredAtoms.eq( nextIndex ).find('.audio').mb_miniPlayer_play();
    }



  **//Inifinite Scroll**

  var $container = $('#container');

  $container.isotope({
    itemSelector : '.square'
  });

  $container.infinitescroll({
    navSelector  : '#page_nav',    // selector for the paged navigation 
    nextSelector : '#page_nav a',  // selector for the NEXT link (to page 2)
    itemSelector : '.square',     // selector for all items you'll retrieve
    loading: {
        finishedMsg: 'No more pages to load.',
        img: 'http://i.imgur.com/qkKy8.gif'
      }
    },

    // call Isotope as a callback
      function( newElements ) {
      var $newElements = $(newElements);

      AudioEvents( $newElements );

      // add hover events for new items
      bindSquareEvents( $newElements );

      setTimeout(function() {
      $container.isotope('insert', $newElements );
      }, 1000);
      });
  });
```

Has anyone experienced this. I presume my jquery code is incorrect or missing something, but I don't know what.

Here is the HTML markup... The div that is changing is .download. The css settings for 'Top' on the loaded pages need to make it look proper is top:-114 while the newly loaded pages only need top:-24 to look proper.

```
<div class="square techno">

<!-- DJ Picture -->
<img src="Pictures/dirtyharris.jpg" class="img1" />
        <div class="boxtop">
        <span class="genre">Techno</span>
        </div>

        <div class="box">
        <a class="close" href="#close">&times;</a>
        <!-- DJ Name -->
        <h1> ThreeSixty & Dirty Harris</h1>

        <!-- Song Title -->
        <h2>Louka (Funkagenda Re-Edit)</h2>

         <!--Song Description(179 characters with spaces)-->
        <h4>I had to include this one since it literally took over control of me while driving the other morning. I was bouncing around in my seat like a little kid who desparately needs to use the bathroom. </h4> 

            <div class="buttons">
            <!--Song file info-->
            <div class="player">
            <a id="m85" class="audio {skin:'#010101',showVolumeLevel:false,showTime:false,showRew:false,ogg:'MP3/Adrian Lux feat. The Good Natured - Alive (Extended Mix).ogg'}" href="MP3/Adrian Lux feat. The Good Natured - Alive (Extended Mix).mp3"></a></div>


                <!--Download Link-->
                <div class="download">
                <a href="MP3/ThreeSixty, Funkagenda - Loudka (Funkagenda Re-Edit).mp3" title='Right Click and Save Link As'>
                <img src="img/dlicon.png"/></a>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont see any changes made to CSS in your jquery.  CSS is not dynamic to style changes by itself based on pages.  Sure it can be manipulated by Jquery or php, but again I dont see this.

Comment: I figured out that there was a problem with the way I was using the callback. the css wasn't changing, it was actually loading another player on top of the existing one, which as a result would lower the div out of sight. Working on why the callback wasn't working properly.